# Control the tab in which an externally called URL is opened

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, url, tabs

I've got a program (not a web application, but an executable) that spews URLs, the URLs are handled by Internet Explorer by default.
The problem: Each URL is opened in a new tab whereas it should be the same tab.

If it's relevant: I'm trying to match an interface of an old (web)application to a new one. The URL is redirected on the server. In the old situation, the URL would open a webpage, start an Active-X control and then close the browser. I'm not in such position now, I cannot use that technique because the new application is a full fledged zero footprint webapp.

Remember that I can't control the browser. It's not opened by me so I cannot do fancy stuff in Javascript for instance.

How to handle this? The best thing I can come up with is changing settings in Internet Explorer, so that it'll always throw away what is in the current tab and replace it with the new URL. Is this possible at all?

I'm not even interested in the tabs as such, if I can always open URLs in an running browser in for instance the first tab I'll be a happy camper.

Answer (score 0):

Thank heaven for co-workers.

In Internet Explorer do *Alt+T, O* to start the internet options dialog.
In the dialog click the button '*Tabs*' and the dialog '*Tabbed browser settings*' appears.

Here in '*Open links from External programs in:*' select the option '*The current tab or window*'.

It does have a drawback that whatever browser or tab is active loses it's content when an external program fires a URL, but that's less offensive than opening browser tab after browser tab...